# Git: quick setup for two users collaboration

Tags: git

I've set up my own local repository for co-working with my team-mate. However, when my team mate pushes anything the author of the commit is me anyway. So, I gave up. Maybe I misunderstand things. Can't find any tutorial to do it right. Is there any command line step-by-step script for doing it? I need a workflow something like:

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
git init


git clone ssh://user1@10.100.0.1/home/user1/myproject/.git
cd myproject
touch 1.txt 
git add 1.txt
git commit -m "init" 1.txt
git push


git clone ssh://user2@10.100.0.1/home/user1/myproject/.git
cd myproject
touch 2.txt 
git add 2.txt
git commit -m "test user" 2.txt
git push


git log
commit e4c33dcdacb2115731eecfc6ba979abd84d34137
Author: user2 <user2@localhost.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 19 11:22:29 2017 +0300

    test user

commit b558de56817a4d4a04d670bfa193cb9da5ac6ad0
Author: user1 <user1@localhost.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 19 11:10:55 2017 +0300

    init
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author you see in git log has nothing to do with the ssh user during `git push`.

It has to do with the global configuration, **[specifically `user.name` and `user.email`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-useremail)**.

As long as `user2` is logged on his/her own account, and has a global Git configuration in `~user2/.gitconfig` with the right value for `user.name` and `user.email`, the commits done in that session will have the right name.

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean "As long as user2 is logged on his/her own account"? Can't user2 remotely clone and push on behalf of user2?

Comment: @DanyloKorostil I mean: user2 must have his/her own `$HOME` in which the global Git configuration will reside. If he/she clones the repo from a remote location to his/her local workstation, that local workstation must have a global Git config correctly set, with the right `user.name`/`user.email`.